# Q: Prove that a two-dimensional vector space $V$ over $\Bbb C$ is four-dimensional over $\Bbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

My answer/proof for the question is below.
What I would like to know is if my answer is sufficient and correct to answering the question. If it is correct can I make any improvements?
Thank you.
$$\\$$

Let $V$ be a two dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.
We must show that $dim(V)=4$ when $V$ is over the field $\mathbb{R}$ instead.

Since $\dim(V)=2 $ over $\mathbb{C}$, the basis for $V$ will be two linearly independent vectors $\{{v_1, v_2}\}$. Thus $\operatorname{span}({v_1, v_2})=V$

Therefore, any vector $w\in V$, can be written as $w=c_1v_1+c_1v_2$ where $c_k \in \mathbb{C}$ and $c_k=(a_k+ib_k)$ for $k=1, 2$

We rearrange $w$ as:
$$\begin{aligned} w&=(a_1+ib_1)v_1 + (a_2 + ib_2)v_2\\
&=a_1v_1+ib_1v_1+a_2v_2+ ib_2v_2\\
&=a_1v_1+b_1(iv_1)+a_2v_2+ b_2(iv_2)
\end{aligned}$$

Thus, over the field $\mathbb{R}$ a vector $w\in V$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $\{v_1,iv_1,v_2,iv_2\}$ and $\dim(\{v_1,iv_1,v_2,iv_2\})=4$

Also, since $\{v_1, v_2\}$ are linearly independent it can be seen that $a_1v_1+b_1(iv_1)+a_2v_2+ b_2(iv_2)$ = 0 if and only if $a_1=b_1=a_2=b_2=0$, thus making it linear independent and since it spans $V$, $\{v_1,iv_1,v_2,iv_2\}$ forms a 4 dimensional basis for $V$ over the field $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It's correct.  ${}$